# How to hide all repositories in Gerrit web page?

Tags: gerrit

when i visit the Gerrit web page without sign in, I  can see all repositories in this page,
how can i hidden those repositories without. i don't want everyone can see it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omOiF.png)

Answer (score 0):

To hide all repositories in Gerrit web page from unsigned users do NOT grant READ permission to Anonymous Users in "refs/*" or "refs/meta/dashboards/*" namespace.